# Set EditText to numeric entry in code?

Tags: android, dialog, android-layout

Ok,
I have an app that creates an AlertDialog for input values.  All values are numeric type and I'm using the following code to get the input.

```
public class DialogWithInputBox extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
        {
            String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }
    );
    alert.show();

}
}
```

My problem is, this doesn't work for Android 1.6, but I want my app to work on 1.6.  Is there another way to do this in code that will work with 1.6?  I do not have a layout for the AlertDialog so I can't set it there.

Comment: All methods I see seem to be defined before API 4... which means it should be OK with 1.6.  Do you have the correct API level set in your project preferences, to make sure the problem's within this code?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Where/what errors are you getting?

Comment: The keyboard is coming up, but its in text mode and not numeric mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard of some quirky things happening with the InputTypes regarding numbers.  Try seeing if the phone type will work instead:

```
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably accomplish your goal with the method setInputFilters(InputFilter[]), and pass in a DigitsKeyListener.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFilters(android.text.InputFilter[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFilters%28android.text.InputFilter%5B%5D%29)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/DigitsKeyListener.html